# Words break at wierd positions

Tags: css, drupal, words

I've got a little issue that I think is easy to fix but the solutions I found were not working.

I've got this div with some text in it, and the text seems to be breaking like, hi my na-me is Nel-son where the dashes mean that the word continues on the other line. I've tried `white-space: nowrap;` but then the text just goes out of the div

Here's a screenshot : http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5a3961f

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: No way I'm clicking on a random link! You can attach screenshots to your Q.

Comment: Or you can add a working fiddle

Comment: I can't, not enough rep.. and in fiddle or codepen or whatever the words dont break like I explained in my post

Comment: use word-break:keep-all  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: Thanks, but I fixed it by using hyphens: none;